# Identify the base class from which a property is inherited

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, pattern-matching

In order to clean up my code by using pattern matching, i need to find the common base class from which a certain common property is inherited from.

In the following exemple, the `sender` is a wpf `DataTemplate` consisting of a `Grid` with several `UIElement` on it. I want to initiate a drag event with the source of the data template, a `Vehicle` that can be accessed from any object's `DataContext` property.

I need to find the common base class from which my `UIElements` inherit the `DataContext` property in order to write clean code :

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
   {
      if (e.Source is CommonBaseClassFromWhichDataContextPropertyIsInherited obj)
      {
         var vehicle = obj.DataContext;
         DataObject data = new DataObject();
         data.SetData(typeof(Vehicle), vehicle);
         DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
      }
   }
}
```

@thatguy answered for my exemple : FrameWorkElement is the class I'm looking for.

But my question is more about **the method to determine the base class** : Do you browse metadata ? Is there an intellisense function ?

Comment: Select `DataContext` and press `F12` (go to definition)

Comment: Yes, thanks. This short answer is lost in that guy's more "complete" answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FrameworkElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=net-5.0) type defines the [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=net-5.0) property, so you can match it.

```
if (e.Source is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
{
   var vehicle = frameworkElement.DataContext;
   // ...
}
```

Methods to determine the base class:

- Use IntelliSense to browse the metadata, e.g. click on `DataContext` in XAML or C# code and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> or right-click and select *Go to definition*.
- Google `wpf [Name of the property] property`, look for the
  *learn.microsoft.com/...* link.
- Remember a long forgotten training where it was mentioned or one of the countless blogs or other sites where you searched for something completely different and learned it by accident.
- [Ask a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66031521/6181599), get an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66031694/6181599) (warning, recursive).
- Meet your future self who knows it already through time travel,  but be careful to not break the space-time continuum, been there, done that, hard to fix, even harder to explain.
- Join the dark side and use unlimited power, alternatively become a Jedi and meditate.

Comment: Thanks, but actually my question was more about the method. How did you determine the answer ? Did you happen to know ? Did you browse the metadata ? Is there an intellisense function for that ?
I'll edit my question to explain this better.

Comment: @geriwald Added some methods to determine the base class.

Comment: I'd like the alternative last solution. Can you teach me ?

Comment: I just found the simplest way : F12 on DataContext... I'm really dumb, i was F12ing the class, i never thought of F12ing the property. This brought me right to the metadata of FrameworkElement.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaahhhhh. I'm caught in an infinite loop. This will cause a ... 


Nope, can't do that joke here.